# Retain JQuery UI tab selection even after form post

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I'm using **JQuery UI tabs** where I have several forms within tabs. What I want is to **Retain Tab Selection** even after **Form Post**.

I **don't** want to use **cookie.js**

You can see my code here at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/agibi4/4)

How can I achieve this using other way?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be to ajax post the form. Something like this will do:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $.post(); // do the necessary post here
  return false; // Do not submit the form
});
```

If you aren't allowed to use Ajax, then you can pass the tab information in the url:

```
<div id="fragment-1">
    <p>Form 1</p>
    <form method="post" action="?tab=1">
      <input type="text" value="">
      <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Then you in page load you can select a specific tab:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("select", tab);
```

You will need to generate the tab above with server core or use something like [this](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) to retrieve it through javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hidden field to save the value and then retain on postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#tabs').tabs({
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#<%= hfSelectedTAB.ClientID %>").val(ui.index);
                    }
                });
                $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", [$("#<%= hfSelectedTAB.ClientID %>").val()]);
            });
</script>

 <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelectedTAB" runat="server"  Value="0"/>
```

Simple. Now your tab retains.